# php add a href with variable

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make php display the images as links however I cannot make the same images work as links. I want to have the images clickable so they can be opened to their full size.

small images:

```
echo '<img src="'.$num.'" width=200 hight = 200 alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

I want to make them linked to their full image size, I am trying the below but in vain:

```
echo '<a href="'.$num.'"<img src="'.$num.'" width=200 hight = 200 alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

Kindly assist

Comment: *(tip)* http://php.net/printf

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` tag isn't surrounded by your `a` tag properly.  As long as `$num` is a valid URL, try

```
echo '<a href="'.$num.'"><img src="'.$num.'" width="200" height="200" alt="random image"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code you want to obtain:

```
    <a href="***"><img src="***" width="200" height="200" alt="***"></a>
```

with

- a closing `>` at the end of opening `a`,
- an E in height,
- no extra spaces around = and
- a closing `</a>`

In PHP:

```
   echo '<a href="'.$num.'"><img src="'.$num.'" width="200" height="200" alt="***"></a>';
```